# Temperature of Power Driver ICs

Tags: power, temperature, safety, driver, lifetime

I'm using TI DRV595 power driver in an application requiring several amperes of current. My observation using thermal camera has been that at 3.5 A the driver IC core reaches temperatures around 90 degC. The circuit is rated +/- 4A and has an over-temperature trip point around 150 degC.
In my application the PCB is at around 40 degC of ambient temperature and is ventilated by a fan.

My questions are:

1. Ballpark, How hot can driver ICs get without severely reducing their working life?
2. Assuming no physical contact against other surfaces - are there any safety issues in regard to end user with having circuits running at around 100degC in non-sealed devices?

Assumption: The temperature of the driver does not affect any surrounding components or function of the device.

Comment: *the driver IC core reaches temperatures around 90 degC* Not really, what you can measure is the **package**. There is some thermal resistance between the package and the **die** itself (also called "junction"). So the actual die will be slightly hotter. *are there any safety issues* explain what you mean. Safety as in "no person gets hurt" or safety as in "no devices get damaged"? I would call the last one **reliability**. Safety I only use to describe situations where circuits could harm humans, due to lack of mains isolation for example or risk of fire.

Comment: Note that the datasheet states, with regard to the 150°C thermal protection: *There is a ±15°C tolerance on this trip point from device to device.* So you should keep the **die** always below 135°C with some margin (imagine it is a hot day) so for example 120°C to prevent the protection from activating. Of course, the lower the better. In the automotive world (chips for cars) the chips that sit close to the engine are usually rated for **10 years** operation at 150°C. But that's **not continuous operation**, it is based on how a (heavily used) car is used.

Comment: This driver chip does not appear to be rated for automotive applications so actual lifetime guarantees can only be given by the manufacturer (TI). You'd have to be a **very** big customer to get numbers from TI. So in practice: you're on your own here. Many ICs can handle continuous operation at around 125°C but there are no guarantees. My suggestion would be to try and keep the IC as cool as possible so increase copper areas on the PCB, put a heatsink on the chip etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. By safety I primarily mean human safety, mostly due to fire hazard.

Comment: For every 10C increase in junction temperature (using a conservative value) the device lifetime is roughly halved; running parts very hot deliberately is how manufacturers actually find what life their parts will have at some temperature (usually 25C). In a (military) avionics world, surfaces that can be inadvertently touched should not exceed 65C.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the widths of all traces connecting to your Driver IC.

If you can widen some of those, particularly those running over GND planes (or VDD planes), you can greatly **LOWER** the Driver temperature.

Copper traces have 70 ° C thermal resistance per watt **PER SQUARE** of foil.

A long thin trace, perhaps 1 inch by 0.05 inch wide, has 20 squares of foil and thus 20 * 70 = 1,400 ° C thermal gradient **PER WATT**.

On the other hand, if you can connect your Driver IC to the GROUND PLANE directly, with no trace needed, then Rthermal may be 70/2 or 70/3 = 22 ° C. Which should reduce your 90 ° C and boost reliability.

==============================

In this thermal design, I'm assuming the ground/power planes are much cooler than the Driver IC, thus increasing the heat flow from the IC to the PLANES -------- is a very good thing to consider.

Comment: Is this thermal resistivity to ambient, or what? And what thickness of foil are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. My PCB design and soldering follows most good practices, reference layout and soldering guidelines. I'm afraid your text is not an answer to the questions I posted.